# delete and create resource instead of change in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created dozens of resources using terraform azurerm, but I want a particular resource that needs to be deleted and created every time I do `terraform apply`

Reason : After applying change to that resource , it's not functioning as expected.

Resource : Azure Alert `(azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2)`

I made some changes on Arguments , after that alert stopped working.
And I deleted above alert manually from azure portal , and did `terraform apply` it worked.

Comment: Could you please provide any code base or error screenshots of the issue?  What was the approach that was used? It could be easier to understand the issue of replication.

Comment: In order to delete a single resource, we can specify the target parameter in the destroy command. After that, we can apply.

  Example

 terraform destroy -target <resource_type.name> // delete the target resource
 terraform apply //apply entire infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to taint the resource? 
[terraform taint command](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/taint)
new in terraform v0.15.2:

```
terraform apply -replace="resource.name"
```

taint (deprecated):

```
terraform taint resource.name
```

Comment: How to use terraform apply -replace="resource.name" in terraform enterprise ?

Answer (score 0):

**Terraform apply** will implement all the infrastructure at a time that is mentioned in our **state** file. It is not possible to delete one single resource from that state file. Until it changes or updates the plan command.

Solution:
**Destroy the respective resource via target command**

```
terraform destroy -target <resource_type.name>
```

eg:

```
terraform destroy -target azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules.alert_v2
```

NOTE: Any changes made manually in Azure Portal should not be reflected in the state file. While running the **terraform plan** or **terraform apply**, it will encounter conflict. **Terraform only refers to statefile**; all changes should be made through statefile.

**Sample [code](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert) base to destroy and recreate**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "*******"
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "example" {
  name                = "appinsights"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  application_type    = "web"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  action {
    action_group           = []
    email_subject          = "Email Header"
    custom_webhook_payload = "{}"
  }
  data_source_id = azurerm_application_insights.example.id
  description    = "Alert when total results cross threshold"
  enabled        = true
  # Count all requests with server error result code grouped into 5-minute bins
  query       = <<-QUERY
  requests
    | where tolong(resultCode) >= 500
    | summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 5m)
  QUERY
  severity    = 1
  frequency   = 5
  time_window = 30
  trigger {
    operator  = "GreaterThan"
    threshold = 3
  }
  tags = {
    foo = "bar"
  }
}
```

Step1: Upon running plan and apply, infrastructure will create on portal.

```
terraform plan
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

[image]

upon running destroy

```
terraform destroy --target azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert.example
```

[image]

It will remove from statefile.  now we can plan and apply and see the change